# How to match and cut the string with different conditions using sed?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

I want to grep the string which comes after `WORK=` and ignore if there comes paranthesis after that string .

The text looks like this :

```
//INALL TYPE=GH,WORK=HU.ET.ET(IO)
//INA2 WORK=HU.TY.TY(OP),TYPE=KK
//OOPE2 TYPE=KO,WORK=TEXT.LO1.LO2,TEXT
//OOP2 TYPE=KO,WORK=TEST1.TEST2
//H1 WORK=OP.TEE.GHU,TYPE=IU
```

So, desirable output should print only :

```
TEXT.L01.L02
TEST1.TEST2
OP.TEE.GHU
```

So far , I could just match and cut before `WORK=` but could not remove `WORK=` itself:

```
sed -E 's/(.*)(WORK=.*)/\2/'
```

I am not sure how to continue . Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Do you mean `sed 's/.*WORK=//'`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thanks for reply ! It is working for cutting the WORK= itself

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  However, it copies everything after WORK=

Comment: `/(.*)/d` deletes lines which contain `(` followed by `)`.

Comment: So, try `sed 's/.*WORK=\([^,]*\).*/\1/'`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  I tried it and it copies the words correct but also copies the first word HU.ET.ET(IO) which comes with paranthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -n '/WORK=.*([^()]*)/!s/.*WORK=\([^,]*\).*/\1/p' file > newfile
```

Details:

- `-n` - suppresses the default line output
- `/WORK=.*([^()]*)/!` - if a line contains a `WORK=` followed with any text and then a `(...)` substring skips it
- `s/.*WORK=\([^,]*\).*/\1/p` - else, takes the line and removes all up to and including `WORK=`, and then captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than a comma, and then remove the rest of the line; `p` prints the result.

See [the `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/UI5diC):

```sh
s='//INALL TYPE=GH,WORK=HU.ET.ET(IO)
//INA2 WORK=HU.TY.TY(OP),TYPE=KK
//OOPE2 TYPE=KO,WORK=TEXT.LO1.LO2,TEXT
//OOP2 TYPE=KO,WORK=TEST1.TEST2
//H1 WORK=OP.TEE.GHU,TYPE=IU'
sed -n '/WORK=.*([^()]*)/!s/.*WORK=\([^,]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```sh
TEXT.LO1.LO2
TEST1.TEST2
OP.TEE.GHU
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much !!! Works perfect ! I have got a lot to learn yet .

Comment: @potong No, because the logic is like that: the lines that must be filtered should contain a `(...)` substring. See OP input.

Comment: @potong This must fail. BTW, you should ask the person who asked the question for clarifications. I only answer what was asked.

Comment: @potong Ok, now, after you made it clear, `/WORK=.*([^()]*)/` will fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following `awk`, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/WORK=[^,]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)
  if(val!~/\([a-zA-Z]+\)/){ print val }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                    ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/WORK=[^,]*/){                  ##Using match function to match WORK= till comma comes.
  val=substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)      ##Creating val with sub string of match regex here.
  if(val!~/\([a-zA-Z]+\)/){ print val }  ##checking if val does not has ( alphabets ) then print val here.
}
' Input_file                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for  you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/.*WORK=\([^,]\+\).*/{s//\1/;/(.*)/!p}' file
```

Extract the string following `WORK=` and if that string does not contain `(...)` print it.

This will work if there is only zero or one occurrence of `WORK=` and that the exclusion depends only on the `(...)` occurring within that string and not other following fields.

For a global solution with the same stipulations for parens:

```
sed -n '/WORK=\([^,]\+\)/{s//\n\1\n/;s/[^\n]*\n//;/(.*).*\n/!P;D}' file
```

N.B. This prints each such string on a separate line an excludes empty strings.